# Is it possible to have an AWS Fargate task that doesn't terminate when one of it's container exits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a AWS Fargate task with two containers each running it's own part of a batch job. However, when one of the containers complete and exit, the whole task is killed by ECS. Is it possible to let the task run until both containers exit?

Though it may be anti-pattern, the containers can run independently of each other. They just use very little memory, but are long-running (~1hr) because of dependence on external API calls, so I was hoping to cram more than one in a 512Mb Task because I can't make a task use any less memory. So this is totally driven from a cost-saving perspective and not from any technical requirement. If I have to break out these out into separate tasks, that's acceptable, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't another way before I went that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon ECS will terminate the task if any of the containers marked `essential` exit.  You can have a task definition with multiple containers where some are not marked `essential`, but at least one container in every task must be marked `essential`.  See [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment) for more information.

Comment: Well, that pretty much answers the question. Thank you!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answered your question.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm rate-limited on the number of answers I can accept, sorry, but it should be good now!

Answer (score 2):

You can also go the other direction with this.  Say you want to run an ECS Task that runs and then terminates (for example, if you just want a container to deploy something and then die), and you don't care if it dies on the vine.

Rather than deploying this task via a service, you can directly deploy a task to your ECS cluster, and when it completes, it simply dies as expected, with no concern of the task being re-instantiated.